# How can a frontend UI app (MERN stack) recieve data from an engineer using C++?

Tags: c++, reactjs, arduino, mern

My roommate is an electrical engineer and has designed many machines such as electric door locks that spit out data via C++. I am a fullstack webdesigner. I use the MERN stack.

We want to work together.

I want to create a user interface using the MERN stack that talks to a C++ program that recieves data from an arduino ciruit board. I am a noob and have no idea where to begin. My guess would be for both of us to share data via the same MongoDB database. But I have no clue if this is possible or even makes sense.

Any other suggestions for how I can start collaborating / linking programs to this guy's inventions would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! A crucial info that lacks in your post is how are the information available? Are these boards connected to a local network? Or even the internet?

Comment: So far we just have arduino boards that spit out code via C++. I am trying to figure out if it makes sense to have some sort of shared database that contains user objects that can be accessed via GET/POST/DELETE requests, by both the C++ software that interacts with the arduino boards, and my React frontend UI.

Answer (score 1):

Create a cpp rest api using Cpp-REST-sdk to send/receive data to React based frontend. For more info go to the link below.

https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk

Comment: Here’s an example of what I have in mind:
We have an array of user objects for electronic door locks, each with an ID card barcode property. Users swipe their card to open doors. When a person swipes a card, a C++ program sends a GET request to a database, gets back the full array of users, and does a search for the barcode that was just swiped.  


An administrator can then delete this user from the list of users allowed entry into the building via the UI I create with React. This then sends a POST request which removes the user from the approved entry array.

Comment: Will React also be able to  manipulate state variables within a rest api via POST / DELETE requests?

I want the C++ harware controller and my React frontend to be able to manipulate an object such as this: 
{name: Calvin,
 cardCode: 32a54f65,
 permission: true}